# Why does Windows 10 transfer some things to a USB drive at <5 kb/s?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I am currently transferring a folder to a USB drive. For the last few minutes, it has quite literally been transferring at LESS THAN 1 kb/s... we're talking 10-500 bytes/s..

How is it possible for anything to transfer this slowly and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Disk errors on the source drive (read) or disk errors on the desination drive(write/read) would explain the slow transfer speeds

Comment: An antivirus scan on your hard drive could cause a bottle neck on your hard drive if it is not an SSD.  You will have to check and see in the Task Manager or Resource Monitor what is using your system resources.

Comment: There is nothing abnormal as far as resource usage. CPU: 15%, Memory: 65%, Disk: 40-50%

Comment: is the folder full of many small files?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. It is the entire directory for an ASP.NET web app. So HTML files, lots of CSS, JavaScript libraries etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly not a Windows 10 problem. Happens often when you copy a lot of small files. This is due to random read/write performance bottlenecks.
This is somewhat alleviated by SSDs, but still an issue.

Try copying a couple of large files from the same source to the same target. Should be way faster. If not, there could be a problem with either your source or target drive.